# How do I rotate a subview x degrees?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I want to rotate a subview x degrees (or at least 90 degrees). I want the subwiew to rotate around the subview's bottom right corner. Is it possible to do this animated like in the picture below?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CGAffineTransform transform = 
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);

yourSubView.transform = transform;
```

Comment: Can I rotate it around a given point? In this case the subview's bottom right corner.

Comment: i guess you should change the center of your subview  with the SetCenter method

Answer (score 2):

Yo can do it composing transforms. First translate to the rotation origin, then rotate, then transform back to the original center.  The view you are rotating is v. It is inside an animation just for fun.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
t =CGAffineTransformTranslate(t,- v.bounds.size.width/2,  -v.bounds.size.height/2);
t =  CGAffineTransformRotate(t, -M_PI/2);
t =CGAffineTransformTranslate(t,v.bounds.size.width/2, v.bounds.size.height/2);
v.transform = t;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```