# How to add subView but i want it to rotate to the left/right - Example Inside. (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, rotation, uitextview, subview

I want to add a `UITextView` to another view (as shown below) and want it to be 15-20 degrees rotated.
How can it be done?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679110/how-do-i-rotate-a-subview-x-degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use transformation for that.

```
textView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(textView.transform, M_PI*45/180);
```

I am not really sure about the angle. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi thank you, can just help me with the current value of MI_P ?

Comment: Thanks, but its not working for me - for some reason the textView disappear from the screen.

Comment: try to change the angel value am not really sure about the angel !!

Comment: M_PI *-20/180 should give exactly what you need :)